# Community Wiki type questions, how to?

Tags: discussion

I've been thinking on creating various posts in the form of `Community Wiki` to gather information in an extensive way but I'm not quite sure of how to do it properly, so here is my idea.

**Step 1 present the topic:**
Examples of x mechanic in games, and develop the question.

**Step 2 create a pattern for the answers**:As this kind of question is too abroad and there is lots of valid answers creating a community wiki where people can edit the answer and just add another example seems to be the way to go, plus, to keep it useful for future readers. This pattern would be something like:

> Pattern for debuffs
>
> Game:
>
> Gender:
>
> Is passive:
>
> Duration:
>
> Is cc:
>
> etc...

**Step 3 create an example answer:**
Using this pattern answer the question as community wiki

**Step 4 ask people not to answer but improve/correct the post:**
Review grammar, add/remove/modify elements of the pattern, clarify the question,title...

**Step 5 once this is done "open" the question for the actual answers**

Finally, my concerns are:

Attending to the community rules. Is this the right way to do that?

Step 4 is likely to generate discussion how to manage that; A post on meta? Ask a mod for a chat room?(Not sure how this work)

Anything I miss?

Comment: Note that voting, on meta, usually implies 'agree or disagree' as opposed to commentary on the actual question quality, unless stated otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned, you probably should not engage in creating such 'wiki questions', in the first place.

***I commend your intentions***, but it has already been established that as a Q&A site, wiki-like 'how to's are considered off-topic. This includes as a format for correctly answering broad questions - questions that are too broad are *already* considered off topic.

We *do* having cases where users have created a question, and posted it alongside a community wiki answer. In the cases I have seen, these have been well-organised attempts to provide a *canonical, quality* answer to a question that poses *quality concern* but is otherwise on topic. An example might be a question that is often reasked with minor changes that disqualify duplicate arguments, but ultimately warrant the same answers.

When I see these questions, they are either the work of *mods*, or the work of very-high-rep users, after consider able meta-discussion.

Ultimately, my recommendation is to just leave it alone, for now. If you see any particular question that might provide exceptionally better value as a canonical question, bring it up in chat or on meta, and get feedback from others. If there is value in a community wiki, its worth ensuring that the community would actually *contribute* to it.

That is not to say that you should not post *questions* to help others. If you have a *specific* question that would be considered on topic, and you have already found the answer, you are free to include your own solution at the time of first publishing your question. In this way, you can post a question *with* your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are proposing a plan to create a set of wiki questions that *present information* rather than ask concrete questions? And/or questions which ask for lists of things pertaining to industry trivia or statistics or other census-like information.

That's not what Stack Exchange is about and such posts will be closed for being too broad, being off-topic, or being primarily opinion based.